# Preferring OSPF over Static Route

Tags: networking, router, routing

In my routers routing table I have three routes for a particular destination,

1. Directly Connected with AD value 0.
2. Static Route with AD value 1.
3. Route learned by OSPF with AD value 110.

By default packet reaching this network will take the static route.

However, requirement is that it should take the OSPF route rather than static route.

Could anyone please guide me on this. Is there any tweak to make OSPF route prefer over static route.?

Comment: Change the weight or remove the static route if it isn't needed anyways?

Comment: @Seth we are not allowed to remove the static route, yet we need to make ospf route best path over static route.

Changing weight won't do as static route weight and AD value would be fixed.

Comment: Is there an actual difference between the routes if it's for the same destination? How do you determine that it's the OSPF route that is being taken?

Comment: using wireshark or any traffic monitoring tool we determine that.

Comment: Yeha ... no. The actual traffic wouldn't have any hint of whenever it's using an OSPF, Static or direct connected route at least to my knowledge. If that is wrong please show me a source for that, I would really like to improve. If the target is not the same, sure, but than the static route probably is just shorter/faster in which case you'd have to adjust your OSPF routing to make it the preferred route, adjust the static route or you could follow the option given as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by increasing distance metric, assuming you are using cisco :-

```
ip route "network" "subnet" "next-hop" 111(any value greater than 110)
```

In case of connected routes you cannot increase their metric, But what you can do is define a access-list and route-map. Match the access-list in the route-map and give the result with a desired nexthop, like one explained below :-

```
route-map RM-NAME permit 10
match ip address RM-ACL
set ip next-hop "next-hop address"
```

This will show up as : -

```
route-map "RM-NAME", permit, sequence 10
```

Match clauses:
    ip address (access-lists): RM-ACL 
  Set clauses:
    ip next-hop "next-hop address"

This route-map should be applied on any incoming interface on which traffic is expected to come in from, like :-

```
interface "if-name"
ip policy route-map RM-NAME
```

The above configuration will route the packets to the desired next hop for connected as well as static routes and from there ospf can take over.